# PHP extract key-value in array json and restructure

Tags: php, arrays, json

Any idea on how to restructure the json below:

```
$jsonArray = [{"Level":"77.2023%","Product":"Milk","Temperature":"4"},
         {"Level":"399.2023%","Product":"Coffee","Temperature":"34"},
         {"Level":"109.2023%","Product":"Chocolate","Temperature":"14"}]
```

Expected outcome:

```
 $expected = {"Milk":{"Level":"77.2023%","Temperature":"4"},
         "Coffee":{"Level":"399.2023%","Temperature":"34"},
         "Chocolate":{"Level":"109.2023%","Temperature":"14"}
         }
```

I'm new and my thinking is get the product value in array and again use foreach loop to find the others value? .

Comment: Create an array and use the product as key. Create an object with temp and level from the inputs and add it into the $array[key]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
$jsonArray = '[{"Level":"77.2023%","Product":"Milk","Temperature":"4"},
         {"Level":"399.2023%","Product":"Coffee","Temperature":"34"},
         {"Level":"109.2023%","Product":"Chocolate","Temperature":"14"}]';
$output = array();
foreach (json_decode($jsonArray, true) as $row) {
    $product = $row['Product'];
    $output[$product] = $row;
    unset($output[$product]['Product']);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
{"Milk":{"Level":"77.2023%","Temperature":"4"},
 "Coffee":{"Level":"399.2023%","Temperature":"34"},
 "Chocolate":{"Level":"109.2023%","Temperature":"14"}
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sBmsr)

Answer (score 0):

This made some trick

```
$a = '[{"Level":"77.2023%","Product":"Milk","Temperature":"4"},
         {"Level":"399.2023%","Product":"Coffee","Temperature":"34"},
         {"Level":"109.2023%","Product":"Chocolate","Temperature":"14"}]';

$newAr = array();
foreach(json_decode($a,true) as $key=>$value)
{
    $newAr[$value['Product']] = array(
            'Level' => $value['Level'],
            'Temperature' => $value['Temperature'],
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform this with Loops in PHP. Other answers demonstrate it accurately. I would also suggest to integrate some form of Error handling, data validation/filtering/restriction in your code to avoid unexpected results down the road.

For instance, json_decode(), either assigned to a variable pre-foreach or straight in the foreach() 1st argument will just raise a warning if the original json is not valid-json, and just skip over the foreach used to construct your final goal. Then if you pass the result (that may have failed) directly to your next logic construct, it could create some iffy-behavior.

Also, on the concept of data-validation & filtering, you could restrict the foreach(), or any other looping mechanism, to check against a Product_List_Array[Milk,Coffee,Chocolate], using if(in_array() ...) so the final/goal object only contains the expected Products, this, in the case the original json has other artifacts. Filtering the values can also increase stability in restricting, for example, Temperature to Float.